# width/height 100%

Tags: css

Is it same like to omit width/height CSS properties and to specify them as 100%?

Answer (score 2):

On *some* elements the width acts like 100% (e.g. a `<div>`, `auto` acts very similar to 100%, depending on margin/padding)....but not height, so no, it's not the same as omitting them everywhere.

[Here's a demonstration with `<div>` width/height not set vs 100%](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q37yS/).

Comment: 100% width on a block element is not equivalent to the computed width which is used by default.

Comment: @Matti - The behavior is the same for some elements, but yes, it's not 
*identical*, I'll clarify this a bit.

Comment: @Nick Craver: It's related to many more things besides the element itself.

Comment: @Matti - *That* element's height isn't really, it scales according to the container in *either* situation, seems outside the scope of the question IMO.  Since we're talking about percentages, this can be safely assumed to be affected by whatever container you're in...

Comment: @Nick Craver: The width is a much more complex case. Whether setting `width: 100%` is the same as `width: auto` depends on the properties of the element itself (both inherent styles and styles you set), as well as its ancestors.

Comment: @Matti - That's an *entirely* different question about style inheritance, the answer specifically states how `auto` behaves on a `<div>` as just an example...if you set something else that cascaded then the style is *not* `auto` then is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
width or height equals to 100% work  relative to parent element .
```

[this_example_maybe_useful](http://jsfiddle.net/zPLDt/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same. By default both of them are `auto` which is quite different. See the CSS specs (for example, from [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) onwards) for more information on how width and height are calculated when unspecified.